# Does exist 'finishless'?

Tags: word-usage

I've translated sentence

> 'Life is aimless.'

using a dictionary. But the first what came on my mind was

> 'Life is finishless.'

But I haven't found anything on internet, it seems almost like no one else had this idea before.

Comment: The word that you are looking for may be *endless*.

Comment: Actually, I suspect the word OP is looking for is ***pointless***. But the erroneous conflation of ***finish** = termination* and ***aim, end, point** = purpose* could be resolved using a dictionary.

Comment: He wants to know if such a word exists.

Comment: I can't see why you people don't tell others the truth about how different writers and other people create new words. This word doesn't exist but I don't see why it shouldn't. It is a good word.

Comment: SovereignSun - Finishless isn't a word. Just because authors may be found creating words, you should not advise people who are learning English to do the same.

Comment: Image a task you can't finish because it doesn't have a final stage. I can see many made up words that can be used: finishless, undoable, unaccomplishable, incompletable.

Comment: All of the examples you gave are real words, except finishless. There are very many possible words or phrases you could use to describe something without end, before you should feel the need to invent a word.

Comment: You could use *finishless* in the context of a piece of *unfinished furniture*, say. This piece has no finish (noun), therefore it is finishless. You can attach *-less* to a noun, but not a verb.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers, as usual. "Finishless" would mean "lacking a finish," such as a car or a piece of unfinished wooden furniture that you sand the surface of and stain or paint yourself. (Note the correct word is "unfinished.") A life can be pointless, aimless, purposeless, etc., but it cannot be "finishless." EDIT: I now see Robusto already used the example of unfinished furniture - great minds think alike. ;-)

Comment: As I write, no-one has actually *closevoted* this question. But I'm sceptical as to whether it's On Topic. If we understand the question as asking *Is the neologism "finishless" acceptable in this context?*, I'd say it's Off Topic for lack of prior research. If it's ***Why** isn't this neologism acceptable?* then probably a valid answer could be constructed along the lines of @Robusto's *You can attach -less to a noun, but not a verb.* But essentially it nets down to *Should non-native speakers avoid creating neologisms?*, which is essentially a matter of opinion (I think they *should!* :)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite easy in the English language to create words, following some patterns, especially by adding suffixes: -ish, -y, -less, -ness, -hood etc.

However, these words are not proper English when they are not documented in the dictionaries. They are sometimes used by people in speech, when they (the people) do not find the proper word quickly, in order to be able to continue speaking - and be understood by the other person(s).

> 1. Life is <strike>**finishless**</strike>.

can be rewritten with another **proper** word instead of "finishless":

> 2. Life is **endless**.

However, the meaning of sentence 2 is radically different from the meaning of sentence 3 below:

> 3. Life is **aimless**.

A similar meaning with 3 has sentence 4:

> 4. Life is **pointless**.

Answer (score -6):

English is very flexible, yet it's better not to create new words and use synonyms instead. You can add 'less' to most anything you want and it will be understood in most cases but it's something not common and something you've just come up with.

- **finishless** - would certainly mean: *doesn't have an ending*; *is **incompletable***; *is **unaccomplishable***; *doesn't have a final stage/part*; *cannot be finished*.

As you can see I've used words that don't exist in English, yet I guess 99% will understand me.

You could say: **trueless, eatless, pieceless, getless, goneless** and e.t.c and in most cases many people would understand you through context but it isn't good to do so. Yet, many sci-fiction writers did so.

Comment: I'd like to enumerate all the bad guidance given in this answer, but that might be a finishless task.

Comment: Strange that you don't like my answer.